Flutter App Size İncrease Too much after Updating Dependencies
I create a Flutter app 2 years ago and I updated my App's flutter and gradle files and dependencies time to time but since I knew that there were problems with every update, I had not updated these files and requirements for about 1 year. I changed my computer a few weeks ago, so I had to move the code of my application to the new computer I bought. Of course, I had to install the new updated flutter version on the new computer. As a result, I also had to update the kotlin files and gradle files. When I updated them, I also had to update the outdated dependencies. Even though I struggled a lot with all these, as a result, I was able to make my application run the latest versions for each file and run it. But when I wanted to build my application, I saw that the size of my application increased from 38MB to 80MB. Since my application is also an application installed on the Google Play Store, I know that the size of an application uploaded to the market must be low due to reasons such as speed and compatibility. What could be the reason for such a large increase? Is it normal that there is an increase of approximately 40MB by just updating the files I mentioned above? If not, how can I restore it to its previous state?
My past file 38mb is build with flutter build apk --release, my new file build with this too, to can compare same things. If you want to learn --split-per-abi for my new file it is 65MB.
Im currently using Flutter 3.22.1, Gradle 8.4.0 and Kotlin 1.9.23.
These are my dependencies;
  snippet_coder_utils: ^1.0.15
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.3
  tab_indicator_styler: ^2.0.0
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.5
  image_picker: ^1.1.1
  awesome_dialog: ^3.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.5
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  async: ^2.11.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.2
  google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.7.1
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.6.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  flutter_image_compress: ^2.3.0
  image_cropper: ^6.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.10.5
  rate_my_app: ^2.1.0
  upgrader: ^10.3.0
  share_plus: ^9.0.0

But compared to the past, I did not add or delete any dependencies. I am currently using the same things as I used in the past, I just updated the versions.

can you elaborate more about the size and the APK, does your APK is split per ABI or not? because build of Flutter APKs is all ABI (architecture) by default. this is different how Google Play Store is, where we will use the per-ABI APK instead through the appbundle. if you want to know what is your APK download size on Play Store, you can build with flutter build apk --split-per-abi, then you you'll see approximately what the download size is.

When use normal flutter build apk --release it will be 80mb when I use split per abi it will be 65mb. But its not important my past example 38mb it was normal build apk so Im comparing same things. Why increased too much when I just update my flutter, gradle, kotlin and dependencies.

I see. It is bigger than it should. What dependency did you upgrade?

I edited my question so you can see details and dependencies

I upgraded all of them to latest version

I couldn't find more information about this issue on Flutter specifically, but I found this StackOverflow question which discuss that minSdk 23 or higher will use uncompressed native libs (.so). We need to add android:extractNativeLibs="true" to get the old behavior (compressed libs).

My minSdk is 21 but eventhough I add this code to my project but nothing changed. If you gave -1 to question can you undo maybe someone can see my question and help me because ı really need to fix it

I don't -1 your question. I will +1 your question then. sorry I couldn't help with your issue.

I solved my problem, I wanted to answer it for people who have the same problem. First of all, instead of getting normal output from my app with flutter build apk --release, I took the output with this code to analyze my apk file flutter build apk --analyze-size --target-platform android-arm64 I opened the resulting json file in devtools and looked at which variables were added compared to my old apk file.
And in the librive_text.so file, I saw that a file took up 48 MB in total, with 12 MB for each file type such as x64, x86. When I searched for this file, I realized that this file came with the Rive library. Among my dependencies, the awesome_dialog: ^3.2.1 package started using the Rive package after version 3.0.0, which took up extra space in my application. When I researched, I saw articles saying that normally the Rive package should not take up so much space, As I continued to research the problem, I learned that the size of the Rive package decreased when the ndkVersion was set to "25.1.8937393". When I used the latest ndkVersion, the size of the Rive package in the build increased. Since reducing the ndkVersion is not a healthy solution and I could not find another solution, I had to remove the package. Instead I am using the quickalert: ^1.1.0 package now.
But If you are using minSdkVersion 23 or higher and if your application size increased after increasing the minSdkVersion, your issue is different, you can look for the solution here compressed native libraries. An easily solved problem with adding code to the build.gradle file.

This should be mark as the answer I guess, the compression option link was the thing for me

Just simply build with --split-per-abi flag.
